# How do I package an Outlook 2010 macro for other users?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, vba

What is the best means available from within the MS Office 2010 suite to package up macro code written for Outlook, so that I can make it available to my coworkers and make it easy for them to install and use? We have shared drive space on a network, so passing code files back and forth shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Do you need to package up a rule set too, or just the VBA code? I mean, you can always store the code in a txt file, right?

Comment: I could send them just a text file and have them put the code in a new module. But they would need to learn roughly how the VBA IDE works, and I'd have to show them how to create their own digital signature to run the code. That's a pretty tall order. So ideally, I'd like them to be able to import my module, accept my own signature, and then find the macro so they can run it. No need to hide the code, I just want them to be able to use it as quickly as possible.

Comment: Various options: http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to go into the visual basic editor and press <kbd>CTRL + E</kbd> to **export** the module.

Then place it on the share and others can go into visual basic editor and press <kbd>CTRL + M</kbd> to **import** the module.